# Adding content to XMLView via "addContent" doesn't work

Tags: sapui5

I have the following [XMLView](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View/):

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:data="sap.chart.data"
  xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
  xmlns:con="sap.suite.ui.commons"
  controllerName="MY_NAMESPACE.controller.ChartView"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
  <!-- Panel here -->
</mvc:View>
```

Now, in my controller, I want to dynamically add a [sap.m.Panel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Panel) to the view.
In my `onInit` function, I pass the object of the current view to the method that creates the Panel and adds it to the view.

```js
onInit: function() {
  var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/MY_ODATA_SERVICE/",
    oModel = new ODataModel(sUrl), // v2
    oCurrentView = this.getView();
  this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  this._createPanel(oCurrentView);
  this._createChartContainer();
  this._initializeCharts();
  this._showCharts();
},

_createPanel: function(currentView) {
  var sId = this._globals.panelId;
  var oViewPanel = new Panel(sId, {
    width: "auto"
  }).addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd");
  this._globals.panelState = oViewPanel;
  currentView.addContent(oViewPanel);
  return currentView;
},
```

**However**, the Panel is never rendered:

[image]

But when I call the [`getContent`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View/methods/getContent) function of the view, the panel is listed as an entry.

[image]

---

#### Clarification:

Creating a `sap.m.Panel` in the `XMLView` isn't a problem. Placing this bit of XML into the `XMLView` works.

```html
<Panel id="chartPanel"
  class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd"
  width="auto"
></Panel>
```

**But,** I need to create and append the `sap.m.Panel` object to the `XMLView` at runtime (in the controller), **not** in the `XMLView`.

Now, the problem:
With above posted controller code, the panel objects gets created. In fact, it even gets registered as a content aggregation of the `XMLView`, but it simply doesn't get rendered (see picture above).

[image: view-aggregation]

Any suggestion on **why** and how this behaviour occurs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you need to create it on runtime? In your code all the panels property seem to be static. You could just add the panel to the xml view with the visible flag set to false and once you added content to the panel you set visible to true...

Comment: No, I dont necessarily need to create the panel during runtime in order for the application to work. I was just surprised that the panel isn't rendered when it's created in the controller and I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Enum, have you tried to use the onBeforeRendering code instead of onInit just to check ?

Answer (score 3):

### Issue

`this.getView().addContent(/*...*/)` doesn't work.

### Why

Currently, `XMLView` won't allow manipulating its content via APIs as the [documentation warns](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ca38324d38950f7b790a087f52caceb2b84019b8):

> Be aware that **modifications of the `content` aggregation of this control are not supported** due to technical reasons. This includes calls to all content modifying methods like `addContent` etc., but also the implicit removal of controls contained by the content aggregation. For example the destruction of a Control via the `destroy` method. All functions can be called but may not work properly or lead to unexpected side effects.

This is, at the time of writing (v1.64), still the case.

PS: The above limit applies only to `XMLView`. Other view types, such as `JSView`*, are not affected.

---

<sup>* `sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView` and `sap.ui.jsview` are **deprecated.** Use [Typed Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0) instead (Applicable since v1.90).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

try to put the Panel inside the XML view and give it a property visible="false".

```
<Panel id="panelId" visible="false">

</Panel>
```

In your function you could do something like this:

```
_createPanel: function(){
  var oPanel = this.getView().byId("panelId");
  oPanel.setVisible(true);
  // Other Methods for Panel
}
```

With the oPanel instance you can execute all methods listed in the API:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Panel

Hope this helps :-)

Best regards